# Select query with a selected item from listbox and date range

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm working on a code where I need to select from a list box and from 2 datepicker to display on the datagridview.

My first version of code already worked with just the date ranges, but when I already included the listbox I started receiving errors.

Here's my query:

```
 private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from customer where network_name=" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() +" where date_loaded between #" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString() + "# and #"  + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString() + "#", mycon);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ad.Fill(ds, "load");
        dataTable = ds.Tables["load"];

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            dataGridView1.DataMember = ds.Tables[0].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to know if what is wrong with my query

Comment: What is the error received?  It may be just a matter of the quotes around the string as Mike suggested.

Comment: {"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'network_name=Smart Simply Amazing where date_loaded between #2/6/2014# and #2/7/2014#'."}  it's on ad.Fill(ds, "load");

Comment: I hate to be *that guy*, but this would not have been an issue if you had parameterized the query in the first place. Yet another reason to use them.

Answer (score 4):

Network Name is a text value, so it needs to be wrapped in single quotes.  Plus, you have two **WHERE** clauses.  Replace the second one with an **AND** clause, and wrap it in a set of parenthesis.  Try this:

```
OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from customer where network_name='" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() +"' AND (date_loaded between #" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString() + "# and #"  + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString() + "#)", mycon);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, parameterize your query. Prepared Statements safeguard against SQL injection attacks and perform better. See: [Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html).

I'm not too familiar with OleDb myself (more of a MySQL guy), but it should be something like this.

```
cmd.Connection = mycon;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE " + 
         "network_name = ? AND (date_loaded BETWEEN #?# and #?#)"

cmd.Parameters.Add("@network_name", OleDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@D1", OleDbType.DBDate);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@D2", OleDbType.DBDate);

cmd.Parameters["@network_name"].Value = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
cmd.Parameters["@D1"].Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
cmd.Parameters["@D2"].Value = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString();


OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
```

Answer (score -1):

you have two where in your query, replace the second with and.

```
select * from customer where network_name=" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() +" and date_loaded between #" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString() + "# and #"  + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString() + "#"
```